# How to maximize an expression based on a piecewised function with respect to inequality constraints?

Tags: inequality, optimization, constraints, piecewise-continuity

## Background

I have the input/output transfer characteristics of an inverter as shown in the graph below:
[image: transfer characteristics]
I want to define the [static discipline](http://mit6002.blogspot.com/2010/11/51-voltage-levels-and-static-discipline.html) of this inverter, that is define the boundaries a sender can use to produce a logical "0" or a logical "1" and the boundaries a receiver can expect to interpret the signal as a logical "0" and a logical "1". I also want to maximize the noise margin in order to reduce the sensibility of the inverter to the noise.

## Mathematical issue

I have four dependents variables $V_{IL}$, $V_{OL}$, $V_{IH}$ and $V_{OH}$ (who correspond to the boundaries I mentioned above) and a piecewised function $f$ (who corresponds to the transfer characteristics of the inverter) defined as below:

- $f(x) = \begin{cases} 
        5-0.5x & 0 \leq x\leq 1 \\
        \frac{35-8x}{6} & 1\leq x\leq 4 \\
        2.5 - 0.5x & 4\leq x \leq 5
     \end{cases}$ (P1)
- $V_{IL} - V_{OL} = V_{OH} - V_{IH}$ (P2)

I have to maximize $NM = V_{IL} - V_{OL}$ with respect to these constraints:

- $V_{OL} \leq V_{IL} \leq V_{IH} \leq V_{OH}$ (C1)
- $0 \leq f(V_{IH}) \leq V_{OL}$ (C2)
- $V_{OH} \leq f(V_{IL}) \leq 5$ (C3)

## My *solution*

Because I had no idea about the way to solve this, I assumed from the context:

- $V_{IL} = 5 - V_{IH}$ (H1)
- $V_{OL} = 5 - V_{OH}$ (H2)

I also arrange (C2) and (C3) like that:

- $V_{OL} = f(V_{IH})$ (C2')
- $V_{OH} = f(V_{IL})$ (C3')

From that point, I can write all my variables in function of $V_{IL}$:

- $V_{IH} = 5 - V_{IL}$
- $V_{OH} = f(V_{IL})$
- $V_{OL} = 5 - f(V_{IL})$

Then, I have to maximize $NM = V_{IL} - 5 + f(V_{IL})$. Because $0 \leq V_{IL} \leq 2.5$, I imagine two scenarios:

### When $0 \leq V_{IL} \leq 1$:

$NM = V_{IL} - 5 + 5 - 0.5 V_{IL} = 0.5 V_{IL}$

If I want to maximize $NM$, $V_{IL}$ should be maximum so $V_{IL} \geq 1$.

### When $1 \leq V_{IL} \leq 2.5$:

$NM = V_{IL} - 5 + \frac{35 - 8 V_{IL}}{6} = \frac{5 - 2V_{IL}}{6}$

If I want to maximize $NM$, $V_{IL}$ should be minimum so $V_{IL} \leq 1$.

### Answer

I can now conclude that to maximize $NM$, $V_{IL} = 1$. I can now deduce the other variables: $V_{OL} = 0.5$, $V_{IH} = 4$ and $V_{OH} = 4.5$.

---

My questions are:

- is it possible to solve my problem without modifying the constraints (C2) and (C3)?
- is it possible to solve my problem without make the assumptions (H1) and (H2)?

Also, is my solution and my reasoning correct?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It comes from electronics. The idea is to defined the static discipline of a logic gate. $V_{IL}$, for instance, indicates the maximum input voltage to give to a gate to represent a "0".

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $f$ is the function who takes an input voltage as parameter and returns the output voltage of the gate.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $NM$ is the noise margin. The idea is to have the greater noise margin to make the gate tolerant to electronic noise.

Comment: I assumed it came from electronics, where I = input, O =  output, L = low, H = high. Please update your question and include a section on the background. If you have diagrams, even better. Ideally, you write the section as if you were addressing electrical engineers. One can then try to translate it to a more standard mathematical form.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It's done. I hope it is what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer to my second question: yes, it is possible to solve my problem without making the assumptions (H1) and (H2) because we can deduce them from the premises.

From the definition of $f$, we can deduce:

- if $f(x) = y$ and $x \leq y$, then $x \leq 2.5$ and $y \geq 2.5$;
- if $f(x) = y$ and $x \geq y$, then $x \geq 2.5$ and $y \leq 2.5$.

Then, from (C1) and the modified constraints (C2') and (C3'): $0 \leq V_{OL} \leq V_{IL} \leq 2.5 \leq V_{OH} \leq V_{IH} \leq 5$ (C1').

Now, we can rewrite (P2) this way:

$V_{IH} - V_{OL} = V_{OH} - V_{IL} \iff V_{IH} - f(V_{IH}) = f(V_{IL}) - V_{IL}$ (P2')

To deduce $V_{IH} = 5 - V_{IL}$, we have to analyze the four following cases. Keep in mind (C1').

### Case 1

$4 \leq V_{IH} \leq 5$ and $0 \leq V_{IL} \leq 1$

From (P1) and (P2'):

$V_{IH}-2.5+0.5V_{IH}=5-0.5V_{IL}-V_{IL} \iff V_{IH}+V_{IL}=5$

### Case 2

$2.5 \leq V_{IH} \leq 4$ and $1 \leq V_{IL} \leq 2.5$

From (P1) and (P2'):

$V_{IH}-\frac{35-8V_{IH}}{6}=\frac{35-8V_{IL}}{6}-V_{IL} \iff V_{IH}+V_{IL}=5$

### Case 3

$4 \leq V_{IH} \leq 5$ and $1 \leq V_{IL} \leq 2.5$

From (P1) and (P2'):

$V_{IH}-2.5+0.5V_{IH}=\frac{35-8V_{IL}}{6}-V_{IL} \iff 9V_{IH}+14V_{IL}=50$

This is true only for $V_{IH}=4$ and $V_{IL}=1$, so $V_{IH}+V_{IL}=5$.

### Case 4

$2.5 \leq V_{IH} \leq 4$ and $0 \leq V_{IL} \leq 1$

From (P1) and (P2'):

$V_{IH}-\frac{35-8V_{IH}}{6}=5-0.5V_{IL}-V_{IL} \iff 14V_{IH}+9V_{IL}=65$

This is true only for $V_{IH}=4$ and $V_{IL}=1$, so $V_{IH}+V_{IL}=5$.

---

Then, we prove (H1) from the premises and (C2') and (C3'). We can now deduce (H2):

$V_{OH}=V_{IH}+V_{IL}-V_{OL} \iff V_{OH}=5-V_{OL}$.

It's now possible to find the answer of this problem with the solution I already mentioned in my question.